# Fission in Distributed Morphology - how does it work?

Tags: distributed-morphology

Currently i'm trying to understand what Distributed Morphology (DM, as introduced by Halle&Marantz 1993) is about.
One of the basic operations belonging to this framework is **fission**.
However, i'm not sure if i understand the idea of fission. Let me demonstrate this by presenting the following **made up paradigm for a personal pronoun**:

[image]

I also alreay decomposed the features into binary features (there might be more sophistcated ways to do this):

[image]

Assuming that we only have **one morphem initially** available for insertion, one could introduce the following rule of fission to explain the syncretisms:

[±Obj, ±1, ±2, ±Sg] -> [[±1, ±2][±Obj, ±Sg]]

Note that this rule is not supposed to have any restrictions, so the fission applies to every form of the pronoun. **By applying this fission, the features are seemingly rearranged in a certain order** which will determine the order later when we insert the vocabulary items, at least that's the idea.
What bothers me is that this whole process seems rather **arbitrary**. To me it looks like the order of the brackets after fission could easily be reversed. But let's proceed.

We also need rules for the insertion of the vocabulary items:

- /fa/ <-> [+1]
- /sa/ <-> [+2]
- /ta/ <-> [ ]
- /re/ <-> [+Sg, -Obj]
- /si/ <-> [+Sg]
- /ro/ <-> [ ]

Is this a proper analysis?

On first sight, it looks like it could be. For example, for the first slot in case of *1st Pers Sg. Nom.* ([+1][-Obj, +Sg]), */fa/* is the most specific item which would fit. And since the features reflecting Person are in the first slot exclusively, */fa/* would be inserted at this spot correctly. But again, this looks a bit "too easy" to me.
Anoter irritating aspect to me is, that we have two vocabulary items here without any context (*/ta/* and */ro/*). One is only supposed to be inserted in the first slot, the other one into the second slot obviously. Again i'm not sure if this is a valid approach.

---

Note that actually i'm currently trying to analyze a much more complex paradigm coming from a real language. But to ask my question in a more straightforward way, i decided to make up an example for the sake of simplicity. I'm also reading the original papers by Halle, Marantz etc. but i'm having a hard time understanding them.

**TL,DR:**
In Distributed Morphology, can fission determine the order of morphems?